# Trriger working on localhost but givig error on **Server**

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

My Trigger code is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `OnNewPurchaseUpdateInventory` AFTER INSERT ON `invoice__purchase_items` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE prod_id integer;
  DECLARE qty integer;
  DECLARE qty_old integer;
  DECLARE qty_new integer;
  DECLARE inv_itm_id integer;
  DECLARE cp decimal(10,2);
  DECLARE oldcp decimal(10,2);
  DECLARE newcp decimal(10,2);
  SET prod_id = NEW.product_id;
  SET inv_itm_id = NEW.invoice_item_id;
  SET qty = NEW.quantity;
  SET cp = NEW.net_rate;
  INSERT INTO `inventory__operations` (product_id, is_sale_flag, invoice_item_id) VALUES (prod_id,0,inv_itm_id);
  SELECT i.qty_balance INTO qty_old FROM inventory__summary i WHERE i.product_id = prod_id;
  SELECT ii.balance_cost_price INTO oldcp FROM inventory__summary ii WHERE ii.product_id = prod_id;
  SET qty_new = qty + qty_old;
  SET newcp = oldcp + cp;
  UPDATE `inventory__summary` SET qty_balance = qty_new, balance_cost_price = newcp;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My server response is:

> Error
>      SQL query:
>
> DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `OnNewPurchaseUpdateInventory` AFTER INSERT
>      ON  `invoice__purchase_items` 
>      FOR EACH
>      ROW BEGIN DECLARE prod_id INTEGER;
>
> `MySQL said: Documentation`
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near     'DELIMITER $$
>   CREATE TRIGGER `OnNewPurchaseUpdateInventory` AFTER INSERT ON `inv' at line 1

It would be great if you can help me to find out and correct my mistake.

TIA.

Comment: Why is this tagged php?

Comment: Will you try after changing DELIMITER ?

Comment: I think you have some code before the delimiter statement, which is not properly terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: Agreed with @Shadow

Comment: You're trying to send this to the server programmatically, aren't you... the server doesn't understand `DELIMITER` -- that is a *client* directive.